# Software to bulk upload and schedule videos to Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, uploader

My objective is to

1. Upload videos to a Facebook page
2. Set their title and description
3. Schedule them to be published on a later date

Is there an app or preferably a script that lets you do that?

For example, here is a Python app, [youtube-upload](https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload), that does all three tasks but for YouTube. Is there anything similar for Facebook?